# grunt serve from a fresh Yeoman install returns - Warning: Task "serve" not found

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

After running `yo angular` and then `cd`'ing into the application's root folder (at same level as the app folder, `gruntfile`, `package.json` etc) I try `grunt serve` and I get the above error. Grunt won't start a server for me.

I have searched all over but couldn't find say to run `npm install` and `bower install` within the application's root directory, which I have tried but still the same error.

I've updated and checked bower/grunt/npm and they're all good.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I have found a solution!

http://yang-wei.github.io/blog/2014/06/01/npm-install-issues-plus-angularjs-set-up/

Running sudo on all the installs causes issues on the NPM folder in the home directory. I needed to change permissions of all usr/local folders by running:

`sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local`

`` sudo chown -R `whoami` ~/.npm ``

`npm install -g yo grunt-cli bower`

Now I go through the process again and no more errors!

The above link also seems to be pulled together from a bunch of answers at 
[npm throws error without sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151018/npm-throws-error-without-sudo/16151707#16151707)

Answer (score 0):

The `Gruntfile.js` is not present under `app` directory but the root directory, i.e. `parent` of the `app` directory.

You must run the `grunt serve` form the root directory, i.e. `parent` of the `app` directory.

Comment: sorry - I am doing that - when I say app folder I meant the parent application folder (which contains an app folder and Gruntfile etc). Sorry for the confusion, I'll update the OP.

Comment: I tried ``yo angular`` before replying. It worked out smoothly. Please retry the whole process and paste the error log it it happens again.

Comment: OK. I'll run through the full process on the yeoman site again.
I have node v0.10.29, NPM 1.4.14, Git 1.8.5.2 installed.
Sudo installed --global yo.
Now I check versions: yo - 1.2.0, bower - 1.3.8, grunt-cli v0.1.13, grunt v0.4.5.
Sudo npm install --global generator-angular@0.9.2.

Comment: (apparently I took too long editing the above. sorry, continues:)

mkdir testyo

cd testyo

yo angular

OK so at this point I get a lot of errors as it goes through the yeoman install process... There are a lot if 'Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.' errors but I can't run `sudo yo`.

I'll have to include the npm-debug.log separately.

Comment: Lets try it once again. ``sudo npm i yo``; ``sudo npm i generator-angular``; Then navigate to desired directory. ``yo angular``; Let's see what happens.

Comment: Can't post the error log as it's too big!
Is this a permissions thing?

Comment: It looks like it was to do with permissions caused by using `sudo` on everything... I have posted an answer with the links that got me there. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar error with "task --- not found" message.
I tried bitfidget's solution, but it couldn't help. It seemed to be different problem.
I updated yo and grunt-cli module like this:

```
npm update -g yo
npm update -g grunt-cli
```

and re-created whole project by "yo" command.
This solved the problem.
I hope this can be help for anyone.