# Installing Grunt on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, gruntjs

I tried to install grunt on Ubuntu 14.04 and wrote **grunt serve**

I am getting this error.

```
Warning: Task "serve" not found. Use --force to continue.
```

Aborted due to warnings.

1. I have Gruntfile.js in my project folder next to package.json file
2. When I write **grunt --version** I get:

   ```
        grunt-cli v0.1.13
        grunt v0.4.5
   ```
3. [I tried @Tom P's answer:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667381/node-package-grunt-installed-but-not-available)
4. I have read [Grunt documentation](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started)
5. All Installations done through sudo
6. [Tried this as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24858493/grunt-serve-from-a-fresh-yeoman-install-returns-warning-task-serve-not-foun)

This is the Gruntfile sample code I took from Official Grunt documentation.

```
 module.exports = function(grunt) {
      // Project configuration.
      grunt.initConfig({
      pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
      uglify: {
                 options: {
                 banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %> */\n'
      },
      build: {
                 src: 'src/<%= pkg.name %>.js',
                 dest: 'build/<%= pkg.name %>.min.js'
      }
    }
});

    // Load the plugin that provides the "uglify" task.
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');

   // Default task(s).
   grunt.registerTask('default', ['uglify']);

 };

   module.exports = function(grunt) {
    // Project configuration.
    grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    serve:{
              options: {
                      port: 8000
              }
    },
    uglify: {
            options: {
              banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %> */\n'
            },
            build: {
              src: 'src/<%= pkg.name %>.js',
              dest: 'build/<%= pkg.name %>.min.js'
            },
          }
     });

   // Load the plugin that provides the "uglify" task.
   grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
   grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-serve');

  // Default task(s).
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['uglify']);
```

}

Comment: What's the anonymous downvote for?  Not very helpful to a new user.

Comment: Then the Gruntfile that is loaded does not contain the task `serve`. If your Gruntfile does include a `serve` task, then you might run grunt in the wrong directory. You should at least show the part of the Gruntfile where you define that task.

Comment: @I_AM_NOT_A_CODER if you can share the contents of your `Gruntfile.js` it might help diagnose the problem

Comment: might be useful to add your gruntfile, to see what your `serve` task is supposed to do.

Comment: I want to know that you have to copy this code from the documentation for creating a gruntfile?   can't we do like what we do for package.json by writing npm-init.

Comment: You haven't registered for the `serve` task. So it is not running. Executing `grunt` will run your default task, which will in turn run uglify task and will uglify the files in specified location.

Comment: There are various npm packages which you can view as a library with built-in functionalities. So you need to write tasks to make use of it. And so you need to include the npm package before use `grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');` . Everytime you cannot copy the same code. You have to build or tailor the gruntfile according to your requirement.

Comment: I have to install the required modules and find the Gruntfile inside my node_modules?

Comment: But if you tried Tom P's answer, why is grunt installed globally? It should be installed within you node project.

Comment: I was getting errors, I have modified the Gruntfile, the server is up but auto reload is not working. Looking into it.

Comment: You return two different functions from `gruntfile.js`. The first one which is probably being executed doesn't have `serve` task